# Missing required module 'libxml2'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have this error

> Missing required module 'libxml2'

[image]

On my import

[image]

I have the module on my linked library

[image]

Comment: Command + Swift + K, Clear your project and try again.

Comment: You should only add one version of libxml to the linked frameworks and libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Build Settings add

- *Header Search Paths*: `$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2`
- *Other Linker Flags* : `-lxml2`

Adding `libxml2` explicitly in *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* is not needed in Xcode 8.

Comment: I have this error now : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h:13:10: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead

Comment: Did you try to use "" instead of <> ? I have a lot of projects including libxml2 without any problems

Comment: Fixed with ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES in Build settings additionally to your solution. Thx man